# Installing Altimesh Hybridizer

Tags: gpu, visual-studio

[Installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUs2o.jpg)I am trying to install Hybridizer in my Visual Studio 2019. After installing the extension, I can't find it in Tools->Hybridizer. What should I do?

Comment: All extensions in Visual Studio 2019 are forced to use the Extensions menu. Did you look there yet?

Comment: Yes, I looked everywhere, but in vain.

Comment: I installed it and it does show up [in the extensions menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJdkE.png), as expected. Are you sure the installation completed correctly? Does it show up in the VS Extension Manager?

Comment: It's supposed to be installed correctly, but it isn't shown neither in Extensions menu nor in Extension Manager!!!

Comment: So then try reinstalling, I guess.

Comment: Tried more than once, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They had a problem with VS 2019, even with the latest version, August 29th 2019, I had to install it manually by clicking the "Altimesh.HybridizerExtension.Professional.vsix" from
[Program Files]\Altimesh\Hybridizer Essentials.
You can check the details from here [VS2019 Bug](https://github.com/altimesh/hybridizer-basic-samples/issues/85)

**Update**
The new version released on September 5th 2019 installed automatically without the need of any other steps.